# Error al mandar mi proyecto a produccion Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5, angular-cli

Estoy teniendo un pequeño inconveniente al tratar de mandar mi proyecto a produccion con el comando `ng build --prod`. Despues de ejecutar dicho comando el realiza una compilacion exhaustiva (AOT) a comparación de la ejecución del comando `ng serve` que a su vez realiza una compilación pero no genera error o advertencia alguna en cuanto a la funcionalidad que he desarrollado (Pagina Maestro - Detalle), a continuación especifico con mas detalle:

**Angular Cli / Detalle Error**

```
C:\Users\Johan Corrales\Documents\GitHub\inventory>ng build --prod

Date: 2018-07-17T16:13:13.004Z
Hash: 7c51a01b7d98bff3951d
Time: 18195ms
chunk {scripts} scripts.e0a8f821933ac7e59b03.js (scripts) 154 kB  [rendered]
chunk {0} runtime.a66f828dca56eeb90e02.js (runtime) 1.05 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {1} styles.fa70ecd2f42fd8700239.css (styles) 141 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {2} polyfills.207dcc605630215505f5.js (polyfills) 130 bytes [initial] [rendered]
chunk {3} main.f58b96bf9bf614ca37d4.js (main) 128 bytes [initial] [rendered]

ERROR in src\app\detalle-bodega\detalle-bodega.component.html(35,112): : Property 'nombre_bodega' does not exist on type 'any[]'.
src\app\detalle-bodega\detalle-bodega.component.html(39,110): : Property 'fecha_bodega' does not exist on type 'any[]'.
src\app\detalle-bodega\detalle-bodega.component.html(43,112): : Property 'ciudad_bodega' does not exist on type 'any[]'.
src\app\detalle-bodega\detalle-bodega.component.html(51,115): : Property 'direccion_bodega' does not exist on type 'any[]'.
src\app\detalle-bodega\detalle-bodega.component.html(55,112): : Property 'numero_bodega' does not exist on type 'any[]'.
src\app\detalle-bodega\detalle-bodega.component.html(59,112): : Property 'codigo_bodega' does not exist on type 'any[]'.
```

**Pagina Maestro**

```
<div class="card"  *ngFor="let bodega of listadoBodegas, index as id">
                <div class="card-header">
                  <h4 class="my-0 font-weight-normal">
                    {{bodega.nombre_bodega}}
                  </h4>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h2 class="card-title pricing-card-title">N° {{bodega.numero_bodega}}</h2>
                  <ul class="list-unstyled mt-3 mb-4 text-left">
                    <li>
                      <strong>Ciudad:   </strong> {{bodega.ciudad_bodega}}.
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <strong>Dirección:</strong> {{bodega.direccion_bodega}}.
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <strong>Código:   </strong> #{{bodega.codigo_bodega}}.
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <strong>Creación:   </strong> 2 días atrás ({{bodega.fecha_bodega}}).
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="card-footer text-muted">
                  <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-block btn-outline-primary" [routerLink]="['/detalle-bodega', id]">Detalles</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-block btn-outline-danger"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalEliminar">Eliminar</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
```

**Typescript BodegaComponent**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
//Importacion de servicios
import { BodegaService } from './../services/bodega.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-bodega',
  templateUrl: './bodega.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./bodega.component.css']
})
export class BodegaComponent implements OnInit {
//Declaracion de array
  listadoBodegas:any[] = [];

  constructor(private _service:BodegaService)
  {
    this.listadoBodegas = _service.consultarBodega();
  }
}
```

Entonces al hacer click en el botón "Detalle", debe de abrir una página nueva donde se cargan los datos en un formulario:

**Pagina Detalle**

```
<form>
                <div class="form-row">
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group text-left">
                      <label class="">Bodega</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control border-primary" placeholder="Nombre de la bodega" [value]="listadoBodegas.nombre_bodega">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group text-left">
                      <label class="">Fecha de Registro</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control border-primary" placeholder="Fecha de registro" [value]="listadoBodegas.fecha_bodega" disabled>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group text-left">
                      <label class="">Ciudad</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control border-primary" placeholder="Ciudad de la bodega" [value]="listadoBodegas.ciudad_bodega">
                    </div>
                    <hr>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-success">Actualizar</button>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group text-left">
                      <label class="">Dirección</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control border-primary" placeholder="Dirección de la bodega" [value]="listadoBodegas.direccion_bodega">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group text-left">
                      <label class="">Número</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control border-primary" placeholder="Número de la bodega" [value]="listadoBodegas.numero_bodega">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group text-left">
                      <label class="">Código</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control border-primary" placeholder="Código de la bodega" [value]="listadoBodegas.codigo_bodega">
                    </div>
                    <hr>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-danger">Eliminar</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </form>
```

**Typescript DetalleComponent**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
//Importacion de servicios
import { BodegaService } from './../services/bodega.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-detalle-bodega',
  templateUrl: './detalle-bodega.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./detalle-bodega.component.css']
})
export class DetalleBodegaComponent implements OnInit {

  //Declaracion del array para el listado de las bodegas
  listadoBodegas: Array<any> = [];

  constructor(
    private ruta:ActivatedRoute,
    private _service:BodegaService
  ){
    this.ruta.params.subscribe(params=>{
      //console.log("params: " , params['id']);
      this.listadoBodegas = this._service.obtenerIndexBodega(params['id']);
      //console.log("listado: ", this.listadoBodegas)
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Por último tengo el servicio que he creado para cargar y obtener los datos del `array` que he declarado con los datos necesarios para alimentar en las vistas:

**BodegaService**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class BodegaService {

  //Declaracion de array
  listadoBodegas:any[] = [
    {
      nombre_bodega:'Mac Pollo',
      numero_bodega:'200',
      ciudad_bodega:'Per, CA',
      direccion_bodega: 'Via el pollo',
      codigo_bodega:'1000',
      fecha_bodega:'03/05/2018'
    },
    {
      nombre_bodega:'Corosito',
      numero_bodega:'201',
      ciudad_bodega:'Per, Ri',
      direccion_bodega: 'Via el pollo',
      codigo_bodega:'1001',
      fecha_bodega:'03/05/2018'
    },
    {
      nombre_bodega:'INCAUCA',
      numero_bodega:'202',
      ciudad_bodega:'Ca, Va',
      direccion_bodega: 'Centro logístico',
      codigo_bodega:'1002',
      fecha_bodega:'03/05/2018'
    },
    {
      nombre_bodega:'El Bombillo',
      numero_bodega:'203',
      ciudad_bodega:'La, R',
      direccion_bodega: 'Zona Franca',
      codigo_bodega:'1003',
      fecha_bodega:'03/05/2018'
    },
    {
      nombre_bodega:'El Arriero',
      numero_bodega:'204',
      ciudad_bodega:'Ga, Fe',
      direccion_bodega: 'Cerritos',
      codigo_bodega:'1004',
      fecha_bodega:'03/05/2018'
    }
  ]

  constructor() { }

  consultarBodega()
  {
    return this.listadoBodegas;
  }

  obtenerIndexBodega(id)
  {
    return this.listadoBodegas[id];
  }
}
```

Le he estado dando vueltas al asunto, mirando y cambiando las declaraciones del array pero no he encontrado el error. Espero que me puedan echar una mano!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te recomendaria no hacer dumps del codigo completo, pues mucho de ello no tiene utilidad y parte de solucionar un problema es reducir la cantidad de codigo a analizar (en tu caso el error te da la linea exacta en donde se encuentra el error).

En **Pagina Detalle** haces esto

```
<input type="text" class="form-control border-primary" placeholder="Fecha de registro" [value]="listadoBodegas.fecha_bodega" disabled>
```

El error esta que estas usando un array como si este fuera un objeto, listadoBodegas[] no tiene el atributo fecha_bodega pues este no es un objeto, deberias crear un objeto o si quieres modificar un objeto dentro del array con el index que recibes por parametro deberias escribir:

```
[value]="listadoBodegas[indiceDeLaBodega].fecha_bodega"
```

O crear un objeto **bodega: {fecha_bodega: '', otrosAtributos: ''}**' y asignarle el valor de listadoBodegas[indiceDeLaBodega] en el ciclo onInit()

```
[value]="bodega.fecha_bodega"
```

Comment: Respecto al codigo tienes razón, pero quería dar un amplio concepto de lo que estoy realizando. Y con `listadoBodegas` nunca es indefinido, se inicializa en una matriz vacía dentro del componente y luego se reemplaza con el objeto correcto cuando el servicio regresa de `obtenerIndexBodega`. Además de que me funciona sin ningún problema, solo surge cuando voy a enviarlo a produccion

Comment: Inclusive si realizo un `console.log` sobre la variable `this.listadoBodegas` obtengo los datos con el servicio `this.listadoBodegas = this._service.obtenerIndexBodega(params['id']);` y  recupero los datos de la forma esperada.

Comment: `Property 'fecha_bodega' does not exist on type 'any[]'`, tu error te indica el problema claramente, si `this._service.obtenerIndexBodega(params['id']);` retorna un objeto entonces estas declarando **listadoBodegas** como array sin ningun sentido, estas declarando un array y retornado un objeto por lo que en el html tratas al array como un objeto, al hacer el build --prod angular es mas estricto que en modo dev, intenta declararlo como un objeto (lo ideal seria que crees el modelo) e intenta hacer el build.

Comment: si estas usando **listadoBodegas** como un array dentro del mismo componente te tocara declarar otra variable como **bodegaSeleccionada** que sea un objeto y de preferencia hacer un modelo de bodega ya que veo que utilizas mucho este modelo.

Comment: Gracias, ha sido de gran ayuda, sobre todo tu anterior comentario, me hizo evaluar bien que es lo que estaba realizando mal. Por no decir que me lo explicaste con plastilina.